# How to install Denim Update on Lumia 930 in USA

Tags: lumia-denim-update, nokia-lumia-930

I am trying to find Denim Update on my Nokia Lumia 930 (Unlocked) but my phone would not find any new updates. Currently I have Lumia Cyan with firmware update notifier 1.2.10.4.

Other details are as follows:

- Manufacturer Name in Extras + Info : RM-1045_1044
- Mobile Operator: 000-HK
- Configuration ID: 1044.00E37D
- Lumia Cyan
- Active Customer Configuration: 12217
- Application Version: 3.13.2.34

So not even sure if ever that update would get pushed to Lumia 930s in USA, I have T-Mobile Prepaid SIM card in it.

Comment: The simple answer is: *you will have to wait*. There is nothing a consumer can do to skip the queue.

Comment: If you go to settings -> extras+info, what is listed under "Manufacturer Name"?

Comment: I am still waiting for the Denim Update in my Lumia 930 in USA (Which I bought from Amazon.com) and here is the Manufacturer Name in Extras + Info : RM-1045_1044
Mobile Operator: 000-HK
Configuration ID: 1044.00E37D
Lumia Cyan
Active Customer Configuration: 12217
Application Version: 3.13.2.34
So not sure even ever that update would get pushed to Lumia 930s in USA, I have T-Mobile Prepaid SIMM Card in it

Comment: Mobile operator 000-HK suggests a Hong Kong version of the 930, which should now be able to get Denim. See updated answer for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on where you bought your 930 from. It's not even available in the US - its equivalent there is the Lumia Icon.

You can figure out where your phone came from by looking at the details in Settings → extras+info. Specifically, look at "Manufacturer Name" and "Mobile Operator". For instance, on my Lumia 920 bought in Estonia, manufacturer name is "RM-821_eu_estonia_446".

In your case, manufacturer name isn't much help, but mobile operator is set to "000-HK", which according to [this Windows Phone Dev Center article](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-US/OEM/docs/Customization/Registry_values_for_carrier-unlocked_phones) stands for Hong Kong. So your 930 should get the Denim update when it's released in Hong Kong. According to the official [Lumia Update Availability in Asia Pacific](http://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/support/software-update/wp8-software-update/wp8-availability-in-asia-pacific) page, it should now be available, so check your phone for updates.

For more information on determining which country variant Lumia you have, see [this article at Windows Central](http://www.windowscentral.com/know-your-country-variant-lumia-os-updates)